# Prove the Set Contains All Primes Except 2 and 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Given the sequence $a_n = \sqrt{24n + 1}$. Prove that the set $S = \{a_1, a_2,a_3,...\}$ contains every prime number except $2$ and $3$.**

Clearly $2,3 \notin S$ since $a_1 = \sqrt{24 + 1} = 5$ and $a_n$ is an increasing sequence.

For the rest: I supposed (for a contradiction) that $\exists$ an integer $a$ with the prime factorization as $a = p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ where $p_i \notin S $ for some $1 \le i \le n$.

I'm not sure where to go with this, or if there is a better method to use for proving it.

Comment: Just prove that for every prime $p > 3$ you have $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$. Probably it's easier if you prove the more general result that for every $n$ not divisible by $2$ or $3$, you have $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$.

Answer (score 2):

The question amounts to proving that for every prime $p>3$, $p^2-1$ is a multiple of $24$.

So, if $p=4k+m$, where $m\in\{1,3\}$, we have $p^2 = 8(2k^2+km) + m^2$, hence $p^2-1\equiv 0\mod 8$.

Also, if $p = 3k+m$, where $m\in\{1,2\}$, we have $p^2 = 3(3k^2+2km) + m^2$, hence $p^2-1\equiv 0\mod 3$.

Since $3,8$ are coprime, we're done.

Comment: Or simply why don't you take cases $6k\pm 1$? :O

Comment: @Sawarnik I think your comment would better fit as a solution to DanielFischer's suggestion above. Since he didn't post it as an answer, and it represents a distinct (and more general) approach, why don't you post another answer? (FWIW you'd have my vote to accept)